# Eclipse Plugin using Java Fx

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, javafx-2

I have a Java Fx 2.2 Application. Can I use this as an eclipse plugin?

I know there is SWT - FX interoperability.

Can I create a simple SWT plugin and integrate my FX application inside it so that I can create my application in FX which can also be used as an eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to integrate JavaFX in Eclipse Plugin-Development and both are now [part of e(fx)clipse](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2014/03/13/swt-on-javafx-is-now-at-part-of-efxclipse/).

With the *SWT on JavaFX* project, you can develop SWT-based plugins and have them rendered in JavaFX.

With the "traditional" e(fx)clipse project, you exchange the Eclipse Platform renderer for a JavaFX renderer and develop a JavaFX application that runs for example inside Eclipse RCP.

It depends a bit on what you want to do. If you want to deliver a plugin that runs in an SWT environment, you'd probably use *SWT on JavaFX* and use [FXCanvas](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swt/FXCanvas.html) to render your application.